# How to return a key's value of multi-dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this code

```
ones = {1 : "I", 2 : "II", 3 : "III", 4 : "IV", 5: "V", 6 : "VI",\
        7 : "VII", 8 : "VIII", 9 : "IX"}
tens = {10 : "X", 20 : "XL", 30 : "XXX", 40 : "XL", 50 : "L",\
        60 : "LX", 70 : "LXX", 80 : "LXXX", 90 : "XC"}
hun = {100 : "C", 200 : "CC", 300 : "CCC"}

ui = input('type a number from 1 to 303: ')
k = ui
print(ones[k])
```

I am trying to let a user input a number from 1 to 399.

when I used `ones[ui]`, I got a

> KeyError '2'

2 is the number I did input. so, I passed the input of `ui` to another variable called `k`, but I got the same problem.

in the live environment of python (idle), when I write `ones[2]`, I get `"II"` instead of the error above.

So, what is the problem exactly and how can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe we should adapt the "title" of the question - as it has become misleading, now that the answer guys cleared the fog ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant Done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that's because your input is a `string`, not an `int` (using python 3), so you're actually doing `ones["2"]` which fails.

```
ui = int(input('type a number from 1 to 303: '))
```

will fix that.

note that if the user enters "303" you'll also get a key error. So better do `print(ones[ui%10])` for your example (you also have to check for !=0 since Roman digits don't support it :))

Aside `20 : "XL",` should be `20 : "XX",`

My fix proposal with full implementation of number build (also works with python 2):

```
ones = {1 : "I", 2 : "II", 3 : "III", 4 : "IV", 5: "V", 6 : "VI",
        7 : "VII", 8 : "VIII", 9 : "IX",0:""}
tens = {10 : "X", 20 : "XX", 30 : "XXX", 40 : "XL", 50 : "L",
        60 : "LX", 70 : "LXX", 80 : "LXXX", 90 : "XC",0:""}
hun = {100 : "C", 200 : "CC", 300 : "CCC",0:""}

ui = int(input('type a number from 1 to 303: '))
if 0 < ui < 304:
    units = ui%10
    tenths = (ui-units)%100
    hundreds = (ui-tenths-units)

    string = "".join([d[v] for d,v in zip((hun,tens,ones),(hundreds,tenths,units))])
    print(string)
```

Comment: You also need to add `0: ''` for `ones`, otherwise `10` doesn't work :-) Also you don't need the backslash for line-breaks in dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) already explains this:

> The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

So your `ui` is a string but your keys in the dictionary are numbers. So it can't find any match (because `2 != '2'`) and produces the `KeyError`.

As already mentioned by @Jean-FrançoisFabre you need to convert it to an integer:

```
ui = input('type a number from 1 to 303: ')
if len(ui) == 3:
    ones_ui = int(ui[2])
    tens_ui = int(ui[1])
    hund_ui = int(ui[0])
elif len(ui) == 2:
    ones_ui = int(ui[1])
    tens_ui = int(ui[0])
elif len(ui) == 1:
    ones_ui = int(ui[0])
else:
    print('ups')
```

Or better reverse the string and then map each digit to an integer:

```
ui = input('type a number from 1 to 303: ')
nums = list(map(int, ui[::-1]))
```

For example with input `20` this returns `[0, 2]`

---

If you use indexing then you need to change your dictionaries a bit:

```
ones = {1 : "I", 2 : "II", 3 : "III", 4 : "IV", 5: "V", 6 : "VI", 7 : "VII", 8 : "VIII", 9 : "IX", 0: ""}
tens = {1 : "X", 2 : "XL", 3 : "XXX", 4 : "XL", 5 : "L", 6 : "LX", 7 : "LXX", 8 : "LXXX", 9 : "XC", 0: ""}
hun  = {1 : "C", 2 : "CC", 3 : "CCC", 0: ""}
```

I added the number `0` to all of them because then you don't need to special case them and you can just go throw these:

```
print(''.join([dct[val] for val, dct in zip(nums, (ones, tens, hun))][::-1]))
```

The `[::-1]` reverses the resulting string again before joining all parts.

Sample:

```
type a number from 1 to 303: 10
X

type a number from 1 to 303: 303
CCCIII

type a number from 1 to 303: 158
CLVIII

type a number from 1 to 303: 19
XIX
```

The code I used was:

```
ones = {1 : "I", 2 : "II", 3 : "III", 4 : "IV", 5: "V", 6 : "VI", 7 : "VII", 8 : "VIII", 9 : "IX", 0: ""}
tens = {1 : "X", 2 : "XL", 3 : "XXX", 4 : "XL", 5 : "L", 6 : "LX", 7 : "LXX", 8 : "LXXX", 9 : "XC", 0: ""}
hun  = {1 : "C", 2 : "CC", 3 : "CCC", 0: ""}

ui = input('type a number from 1 to 303: ')
nums = list(map(int, ui[::-1]))
print(''.join([dct[val] for val, dct in zip(nums, (ones, tens, hun))][::-1]))
```

Comment: you have to check for length before accessing `ui[2]` or even check if it _is_ an integer. +1 for the indexing though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks again.

Comment: of course there's still the "0" case which is unhandled in roman digits, just being pedantic :)

Comment: I love those ones. Sounds innocuous at start and reveal interesting enough, also because there's some history/"science" behind it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ones = {1 : "I", 2 : "II", 3 : "III", 4 : "IV", 5: "V", 6 : "VI",\
        7 : "VII", 8 : "VIII", 9 : "IX"}
tens = {10 : "X", 20 : "XX", 30 : "XXX", 40 : "XL", 50 : "L",\
        60 : "LX", 70 : "LXX", 80 : "LXXX", 90 : "XC",0:""}
hun = {100 : "C", 200 : "CC", 300 : "CCC",0:""}

MAPPING = {3:[hun,tens,ones],
           2:[tens, ones],
           1:[ones]}

rr = 304
_input = str(input('type a number from 1 to {0}: '.format(rr)))
_out = []

#check range and schema
if 0<int(_input)<rr and MAPPING.has_key(len(_input)):
  for n,sub_dict in enumerate(MAPPING[len(_input)]):
    #ignore zero
    if int(_input[n]):
      # go by mapping values, based on input len
      _out.append([sub_dict[x] for x in sub_dict.keys() if _input[n] in str(x)])

print _out


>>>type a number from 1 to 304:  201
>>>[['CC'], ['I']]

>>>type a number from 1 to 304:  74
>>>[['LXX'], ['IV']]

>>>type a number from 1 to 304:  303
>>>[['CCC'], ['III']]

>>>type a number from 1 to 304:  123
>>>[['C'], ['XX'], ['III']]
```